# Windows Service Upload to AWS S3

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to create a windows service that periodically checks a folder and uploads any new files that were created into an S3 bucket.

It seems that the code is not finding my app.config file and thus not locating the AWSProfileName or any other values.

```
 private bool Upload(List<string> files,string bucketname, RegionEndpoint bucketRegion)
    {
        IAmazonS3 S3Client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
        TransferUtility tranUtil = new TransferUtility(S3Client);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            tranUtil.Upload(file, bucketname, file.Replace(configFolderPath, ""));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Throws me this exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

here's my app config too (with values removed)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <!--AWSProfileName is used to reference an account that has been registered with the SDK.
If using AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio then this value is the same value shown in the AWS Explorer.
It is also possible to register an account using the <solution-dir>/packages/AWSSDK-X.X.X.X/tools/account-management.ps1 PowerShell script
that is bundled with the nuget package under the tools folder.
-->
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="******" />
    <add key="profile" value="******" />
    <add key="region" value="******" />
    <add key="configuration" value="******" />
    <add key="framework" value="netcoreapp2.1" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I can run the exact same code & app.config in a console app and it will upload the files without any trouble.

I have also tried to break out the credentials:

```
private bool Upload(List<string> files,string bucketname, RegionEndpoint bucketRegion)
        {
            AWSCredentials creds = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials("My AWS Profile Name");
            IAmazonS3 S3Client = new AmazonS3Client(creds, bucketRegion);
            TransferUtility tranUtil = new TransferUtility(S3Client);...
```

only to get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'App.config does not contain credentials information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey properties or the AWSProfileName property.'
```

But I DO have the AWSProfileName in the config...

What's going on with the Windows service that breaks this?

### **Workaround Found**

I was following this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example1.html)

After properly setting up a user's IAM policies you can manually set the access key and secret yourself using an overload of the S3 client constructor. Obviously would want to load that from a file outside of the project.

```
        IAmazonS3 S3Client = new AmazonS3Client("IAM USER ACCESS KEY ID", "IAM USER ACCESS KEY SECRET", bucketRegion);
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from settings? how are you invoking the method that is throwing the exception? The way you fetch from settings is the same in a windows service as it is in a console app so I dont see that being the issues. Have you checked to see Files is not null or the bucket youre passing in?

Comment: Check the user that your service is running under has access to the .aws/credentials file that has the profile you are specifying.

Comment: 1: Data is in the default app.config file. The AWS templates just have the settings in this file and it seems to be the default file that the S3Client look for. If there is a way to specify this that might fix the issue but I don't know how.

Comment: 2: The "TransferUltility.Upload(filePath, BucketName, KeyName)" function is the one throwing errors. I am invoking this function on a 60 second timer and can see it hit breakpoints in this function without problem.

Comment: 3: can confirm that I can see the files and bucket name when break pointed in the function.

Comment: 4: where is this .aws/credentials file? I haven't seen that file in any of the example templates

Comment: You can create the credentials file by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command. In fact, have you considered using `aws s3 sync` to copy the files, rather than writing your own code?

Comment: @Zeckal Were you successful in getting this working? I have been trying to do something similar, but haven't had much success.

Answer (score 2):

When you build a Windows Service in release mode your app.config file is converted by Visual Studio into a file called yourprogram.exe.config. Check that this config file contains the connection information. This file must be in the same location as the exe.

Your config is specifying a profile contained in the SDK Store. SDK Store profiles are specific to a particular user within a particular host.

When you run the app in a console, you are running it under your user account. The app will be able to look in your SDK Store and find the profile and the associated credentials.

When you run the app as a service it will be using a different user account; it will therefore not be able to find the profile in the SDK Store and so will not be able to connect.

You could create a credentials file and link that e.g:

```
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="AWSProfileName" value="xxxxxx"/>
        <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\aws_service_credentials\credentials"/>
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

You use a text editor to manage the profiles in a credentials file. The file should be named credentials and stored in the location you specify in AWSProfilesLocation

Each profile has the following format:

```
[{profile_name}]
aws_access_key_id = {accessKey}
aws_secret_access_key = {secretKey}
```

More Information:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html

Comment: It seems that I am having trouble even reading my app.config file with the service.
I attempted to specify "AWSProfilesLocaiton" in the app config but still failed out with
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: Thanks for the link, it did lead me around to the workaround I found.
I still don't have a solution to it failing to find the app.config values, if you have any thoughts on that.

Comment: Added a new first paragraph to explain that when you build and install a service using the Visual studio service installer it will add the config information into an exe.config file.